# Add and delete form in the same row in which button is clicked in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular material table having 3 rows. The last row has forms and add and delete button. On click of Add button, a new form should be added in the same row. But in my case it is adding forms in all the rows.

```
<div *ngIf='displayTable'>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 1000px;">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="hotelName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Hotel Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hotelName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="hotelAddress">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Hotel Address </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hotelAddress}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="hotelCode">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Hotel Codes </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
          <form class="basic-container" [formGroup]="hotelCodesForm">
            <div formArrayName="hotelsArray">
                <div class="row" *ngFor="let hotelsArrayOutside of gethotelCodesOutside(hotelCodesForm) ; let i = dataIndex"
                [formGroupName]="i">
                <div formArrayName="insideHotelsArray">
                  <div *ngFor="let insideHotelsArray of gethotelCodesInside(hotelsArrayOutside); let f=index;" [formGroupName]="f">
                <mat-form-field class="col-4">
                 <mat-label>Source</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="sourcesControl">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of source" [value]="source">{{element}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field class="col-5">
                  <mat-label>Hotel Codes</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Hotel Codes" formControlName="hotelCodes"> 
                </mat-form-field>
                <div class="col-10">
                <button mat-button (click)="onDelete(i)" matTooltip="Delete">
                  <mat-icon class="delete-icon">delete</mat-icon> 
                </button>
                <button mat-button (click)="onAdd(element,i)" matTooltip="Add">
                  <mat-icon class="add-icon">add_box</mat-icon>  
                </button>
              </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="getRow(row)"></tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div class="button-style">
     <button mat-button color="primary" style="align-content: center; background-color: #3586C9;color: white" (click)="createPayload()">Save</button>
    </div>
```

.ts file is:

```
export interface Locations {

  city: string;
  province: string;
  locationCode: string;
  locationName: string;
}
export interface HotelCodes{
  hotelAddress: string,
  hotelName: string,
  hotelCodes: string,
  hotelId: number
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: HotelCodes[] =[
  { hotelAddress: "ABC Avenue, New York City, USA", hotelName: "Radisson Hotel", hotelCodes: "ABC", hotelId: 25 },
  { hotelAddress: "XYZ Avenue, London, UK", hotelName:"Hotel Le Meridian", hotelCodes: "XYZ", hotelId: 30 }
];

export class HotelCodesComponent implements OnInit {
  public hotelCodesForm: FormGroup;
  hotelsArray: FormArray;
  hotelIndex: number;
  buttonClicked: false;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['hotelName', 'hotelAddress', 'hotelCode'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  locationSelected: string;
  searchHotel = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
  displayTable = false;
  payloadInfo: any[];
  source: string[] =["Nexus", "DHISCO"];


  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  locationNamesControl = new FormControl();
  filteredLocations: Observable<(Locations)[]>;
  loc: (Locations)[];
  constructor(public hotelCodesService: HotelCodesService,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hotelCodesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      hotelsArray: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.createOutsideFormsGroup()
      ])
    });
    this.hotelCodesService.getLocations().subscribe((location: (Locations)[]) => {
      this.loc = location;
      this.filteredLocations = this.locationNamesControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.locationName),
          map(locationName => locationName ? this._filter(locationName) : this.loc.slice())
        );
    });

  }

  private _filter(locationName: string): Locations[] {
    const filterValue = locationName.toLowerCase();
    return this.loc.filter(loc => loc.locationName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }


  locationChanged(event) {
    if (this.locationNamesControl.value === Constants.EMPTY_STRING) {
      //will do something here
    }
  }

  displayLocationNamesFn(location: Locations): string {
    return location && location.locationName ? location.locationName : Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
  }

  getPosts(option)
  {
    this.displayTable = true;
    this.locationSelected =option.locationCode;
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string)
  {
    
  }
  getRow(row){
    console.log(row);
  }

  onAdd(e, f){
    this.hotelsArray =(<FormArray>this.hotelCodesForm.controls['hotelsArray']).at(f).get('insideHotelsArray') as FormArray;
    console.log("Length of array is:",this.hotelsArray.value);
    console.log("Element is:", e);
    let a= this.createHotelCodesFormGroup();
    this.hotelsArray.push(a);
    console.log("Value of console is:",this.hotelCodesForm.value);
    console.log("Length of Array after add is:", this.hotelsArray.length);
    console.log("Length of Array after add is,", this.hotelsArray.value);
  }
  onDelete(i: number){
    this.hotelsArray=(<FormArray>this.hotelCodesForm.controls['hotelsArray']).at(i).get('insideHotelsArray') as FormArray;
    if (this.hotelsArray.length > 1) {
      this.hotelsArray.removeAt(i);
    } else {
      this.hotelsArray.reset();
    }
    
  }
  public createOutsideFormsGroup(){
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'insideHotelsArray': this.formBuilder.array([
        this.createHotelCodesFormGroup()
      ])
    })
  }
   createHotelCodesFormGroup(): any{
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'sourcesControl': new FormControl(''),
      'hotelCodes': new FormControl('')
    })
  }

  gethotelCodesInside(hotelsArrayOutside)
  {
    return hotelsArrayOutside.controls.insideHotelsArray.controls
  }
  gethotelCodesOutside(hotelCodesForm)
  {
    return hotelCodesForm.controls.hotelsArray.controls;
  }

}
```

I want that on click of Add button a new form should be added in the same row not in all the rows.